# Jython on Mac OS Big Sur (MacOS 11)

Tags: python, intellij-idea, homebrew, jython, jython-2.7

Before Mac OS Big Sur was using Jython, installed with homebrew, in JetBrains IntelliJ.

This seems to have broken under Big Sur.  Running projects in IntelliJ using Jython was giving me the error

```
"The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports -Xmx512m"
```

So, I uninstalled and reinstalled ... now IntelliJ won't recognize Jython at all suggesting it is corrupt.

[image]

I've tried installing from the bottle (which seems to be for catalina)

```
brew install jython
```

and building from source

```
brew install jython --build-from-source
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

For context, I'm using Jython to do development in `ImageJ` / `Fiji` using Python.  I realize there's many languages I can develop in in `ImageJ` (e.g. Java, Groovy, etc.), but I'm not comfortable enough with those languages to be productive.  I am able to work in the `Fiji` Macro Editor, but `IntelliJ` allows me to debug (e.g. stop, step, inspect variables, etc) in ways you can't in the Macro Editor.

**Update**

Clicking through allows the Jython SDK to be used but you still get

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports -Xmx512m.
```

Answer (score 0):

The investigation is on-going but ...

### Short answer

The following seems to work.

```
brew install openjdk
brew install jython
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)' >> ~/.zshrc
```

### Long answer

This issue is nuanced and the above solution may not work in all circumstances.  See this [Github issue](https://github.com/jython/jython/issues/125) for a very detailed discussion of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most people get this error because they are referencing the python script file in IntelliJ/Burpsuite that requires a direct reference to the .jar file.

If you installed using `brew`, the actual jar file will be located:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.2/libexec/jython.jar
```

If you'd like to spin up the console, try running this:

```
java -jar /usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.2/libexec/jython.jar
```